# how to use select method with auto complete?

Tags: php, jquery

code:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#college_name" ).autocomplete({
        source: 'search.php',
        minLength:2,
        select: function(event, ui) {
    var x = ui.item.value;
    $("#college_name").attr('value',x);
    }
    });
});
</script>

<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
       $("#college_name").select(function(){
          alert("hi");
       });
   });
</script>
```

html code:

```
<input type="text" id = "college_name"  name = "college_name" value="" placeholder = "College Name" autocomplete="off">
<input type='text' name='college_id' id='college_id'>
```

In this code when I wrote any college name in college_name input field autocomplete search i.e. search.php are working all college are showing. But when I select any college from autocomplete it does not show any message like (hi) or any thing. So, how can I fix this problem.

Thank You

Comment: check my answer below.

Comment: you can try combobox for select autocomplete [http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox)

Comment: @MeeraTank  He want to get alert on select event.

Answer (score 0):

Add alert message in Select event of autocomplete.

```
 <script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#college_name" ).autocomplete({
            source: 'search.php',
            minLength:2,
            select: function(event, ui) {
        var x = ui.item.value;
        $("#college_name").attr('value',x);
         alert("hi");
        }
        });
    });
    </script>
```